# How to know the view id of currently visible view in Titanium Android Alloy App

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I want to find out the id of currently visible  in Titanium Android Alloy App using index.js controller.

How can I do so?
I tried the below code in index.js, but its throwing error.

```
console.log(mainwin.view.id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
mainwin.getView().id
```